# Display image in another activity after capture in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to display my image in ImageView in another activity after I captured the photo.
I have 2 activities(MainActivity,UploadActivity) and 2 layouts(main,upload).

main layout has 1button for open camera and upload layout has Imageview for display image after capture.
  MainActivity for button click to open camera and UploadActivity for retrieve image to display.

this is the MainActivity

```
 imb_eat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_capture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent_capture, 0);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: post the code you have created to execute this task.

Comment: this code I can open the camera but in the UploadActivity I don't do anything because I don't know how to display image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the camera activity finishes, you collect the data in the onActivityResult() method.
Then you can take the file your camera created and use it in another intent and then fire off fire off another activity.  That activity then reads the intent data and can manipulate the photo.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String filePath;
    Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = null;
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    _bitmapPreScale = getPhoto(filePath);

  Intent intent = new Intent(someCLass.class)
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse ("file://" + filePath));
  startActivity(intent);
 }
```

}

Comment: can you show me the code of 2 Activities or your already done project

Answer (score 0):

Here's an activity that accepts a bundle from another activity.  I don't pass pictures or filenames of pictures around, but the mechanism is the same

```
public class ClassList extends ListActivity {


private gradeBookDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the classlist is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.class_list);

    // pull in any calling bundle information - are we just selecting a class from the list?
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
     int id = extras.getInt("SELECT");
      Select = (id == 1)? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: can u fill this project? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927710/get-image-from-capture-and-show-image-in-another-layout-using-another-activity-i]